# Is "cut" a passive or an active verb in "I have my hair cut"?

Tags: passive-voice, causative-have

I got a haircut yesterday because my hair was too long. While I had been thinking to have a SailorMoon's iconic hairstyle, it reminded me of the question that I asked in an English class.

(Aside: I am doing a part-time intermediate level English course. You know, I was expecting a native speaker, but ironically, our school did not give us one. Our English teacher was a graduate from a top school in South Korea.)

During English class, I asked her, "Is *cut* a passive or an active verb in the sentence ***'I have my hair cut'***"?

She said that: ***"I have my hair cut"*** means "I have my hair to cut". But most people choose to omit the preposition *to*".

I asked her to confirm whether it means:

- 1. "I have my hair to cut."

or

- 2. "I have my hair to be cut."

She picked the former (#1), but I picked the latter (#2) in my mind. Since she was very confident, this really made me so confused.

As far as I understand, ***"I have my hair cut"*** means "A gentleman cut my hair for me". So, the word "cut" should be a passive verb in the sentence "***I have my hair cut".*** That means, ***"I have my hair cut"*** is equivalent to "I have my hair to be cut" (#2).

I believe only one of us (either my English teacher or me) is correct, but which of us is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right.

> I had my hair cut = “I caused my hair to be cut”

In this causative construction *cut* is a past/passive participle and *hair* is its Patient, the entity acted upon. Compare the use of a verb whose past/passive participle is distinguishable from its infinitive:

> I had my speech record**ed<sup>PaPpl</sup>** = “I caused my speech to be recorded”, not
>   <sup>∗</sup> I had my speech record<sup>Inf</sup>.

Note that if the *HAVE NP VERB* construction is employed with *VERB* in the infinitive, it does have an active sense; *NP* is taken to be the Agent of *VERB*, the entity which performs the action, and if *VERB* is transitive another NP acting as Patient/Direct Object is required:

> <sup>∗</sup> I had Mario<sup>Agent</sup> bring.
>   <sup>ok</sup>I had Mario<sup>Agent</sup> bring **my notes<sup>Patient</sup>**.

This may be ‘passivized’ by employing the participle:

> I had my notes **brought** by Mario, *which is the same construction as*
>   I had my hair cut [by the stylist].

---

<sup>∗</sup> <sub>marks an utterance as ungrammatical</sub>